# Determining behavior of a dynamical system by using another system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose we have to dynamical systems defined by below equations:
$$
A: \quad \quad x\dot{x}=-(y^2-1), \quad y\dot{y}=-(x^2-1)
\\
B: \quad \quad \dot{x}=-y(y^2-1), \quad \dot{y}=-x(x^2-1)
$$
The problem is:

1. Determine behavior of $B$ near equilibrium points,
2. Show that behavior of $A$ can be determined by behavior of $B$,
3. Show that there is no smooth transformations $u=u(x), v=v(y)$ that transforms $A$ to $B$.

My strategy for 1 is linearization near equilibrium points, but the only idea coming to my mind for 2 is change of variables to transform $A$ to $B$, but 3 asks to show this is impossible!

I appreciate any idea for showing 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An intuition behind 3 is that $B$ has an equilibrium at $(0, 0)$, whereas $A$ has a singularity there (both $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ tend to infinity).

Regarding 2, other equilibriums at $x = \pm 1, y = \pm 1$ are shared, and both systems do behave in a very similar manner there.